# What's the difference - struct std::hash<T> vs namespace std { struct hash<T> }?

Tags: c++

Is there any difference between these two variants of std::hash specialization?

```
template <>
struct std::hash<T> {
  size_t operator()(const T& x) const {
    return ...;
  }
};
```

```
namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<T> {
  size_t operator()(const T& x) const {
    return ...;
  }
};
} // end of std
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one:

```
template <>
struct std::hash<T> {
  size_t operator()(const T& x) const {
    return ...;
  }
};
```

Is non standard. It's an extension provided by your compiler and is non portable.

This one:

```
namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<T> {
  size_t operator()(const T& x) const {
    return ...;
  }
};
} // end of std
```

Is standard C++